# How to start one activity from another using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I have my activity extending DroidGap. I need to start another activity on a button click. The button is inside the webview that is loaded inside the window.

If any one is having any idea, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Add click event for button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="your_button.performClick();">Your Button</button>
```

Set click event in WebView :

```
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
  public void performClick() {
    // Your can start Activity here
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       // set Activity which you want to start
       // Set flags, actions and other parameters if required
       this.cordova.startActivity(intent);
  }
}, "your_button");
```